# Global array won’t get logged

Tags: javascript, jquery

This scope issue is driving me crazy.

I have

```js
var foo = ["apples", "bananas", "grapes"];

$(document).ready(function(){
       $(select).change(function(){
             console.log(foo);
       })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The array won’t exist within the console log. How can I bring it there?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Please, [edit] your question and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: who is `select`? can you provide that code?

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that was an example to say that my array "foo" is out of the function "change", so within that scope is undefined. Thus, how can I bring it inside?
I tried to write something like function(foo) but it is not working properly. The array is not undefined anymore but it's not an array but something else. Sorry I'm a beginner with programming.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your jQuery selector for select, not scope. Try to put id on the select element then get it with $('#id').change , or put brackets

```
$('select')
```